# How to gain root acess over files/folders in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

Right now, I am logged in with my account by default and I want to access some files/folders in my machine. I am unable to access (also no copy/paste) those because I am not logged in as root user. Is there a way to gain root access over those files/folders in Ubuntu? I know i can do `su` in command prompt and change the permissions but what is the other way to gain root access?

Comment: See also [Get root access for copying files to /usr/share/…?](http://askubuntu.com/q/10435/1059) on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/), and (not Ubuntu-specific so not everything will apply) [How do I run a command as the system administrator (root)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3063/885).

Answer (score 4):

```
gksu nautilus
```

is probably what you want. If you enter it in a terminal or with Alt+F2, it will first ask for your password and then open a folder view of your home directory, from where you can navigate normally.
Or you could use

```
gksu nautilus foldername
```

to access the folder you want directly.
If you are using Kubuntu, replace "nautilus" with "dolphin".

Answer (score 3):

CarlF is on point. `sudo` is the command that you want to use to act as a root user.

You must prefix all of your commands with `sudo` in order to act as the `root` user. Also, in Ubuntu, **there is no root user that you can log in as** (unless you re-enable it or you su to it from another user), so the computer does not have a root password -- you only have to provide your own password if you exist in the `sudoers` file in /etc (I believe) in order to gain `root` capabilities.

Comment: There is a root user. It's just not allowed to log in.

Answer (score 2):

Actual there is a root account on ubuntu. Hera step by step tutotial how to get on the root accout.

```
username@pcname:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for username: *****
```

After this you see something line this below.

```
root@pcname:~#
```

!! This enables onlt the root account. It has no password yet. Just typ passwd when you are in root and you can set a new password.

when you want to disable the root account you can just typ

```
username@pcname:~$ sudo passwd -dl root
```

More information of this can be found on [here (Ubuntu documentation)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `man sudo`.

This will open the *manual* page for the `sudo` command.

`sudo` is used to perform a given command with superuser privileges.

Comment: why can't i directly access a folder by providing my root password for authentication :(

Comment: You must prefix all of your commands with sudo in order to act as the root user.

Comment: If you want to enter a bunch of commands as root in Ubuntu and don't want to type the bothering sudo everytime, do a "sudo su" to change into superuser. But remember to do an "exit" as soon as you're done doing root stuff...